# Detaching Rows in Pivot Table - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a pivot table `country_team` with data in this form

**country_team**

```
 country_id    team_id  
     1            1
     1            2
```

**Country**

```
   id    name 
    1    Spain
```

**Team**

```
 id     name
  1     Barcelona
  2     Real Madrid
```

In my table, i have it displayed in this form

**Table**

```
 Country_id    Team
     1         Barcelona
     1         Real Madrid
```

Now, i want to detach real Madrid from the row but how can get the id of real madrid or get the name `Real Madrid` to detach it. I cannot delete using country_id since it will delete all teams belonging to that particular country .

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $countries = Country::where('id',Auth::user()->id)->get();

    return view('admin.order.index',compact('orders'));
}

public function deleteTeam()
{
    $get_country_id = Country::findOrFail($id);  
    $get_country_id->teams()->detach();  
}
```

**HTML**

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($countries as $country)
        @foreach($country->teams as $team)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$country->id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $team->name}}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally use somethink like this to detach ids.
**Controller**

```
public function deleteTeam($country_id, $team_id)
{
    $country = Country::findOrFail($country_id);  
    $country->teams()->detach($team_id);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($countries as $country)
        @foreach($country->teams as $team)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $country->id }}</td>
                <td>{{ $team->name }}</td>
                <td>
                    <form action="{{ route('admin.team.delete', ['country_id' => $country->id, 'team_id' => $tem->id]) }}" method="post">
                        <button type="submit" role="button">Delete</button>
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

And in your **web.php** you have to add the route in the correct group or something.

```
Route::post('delete/{country_id}/{team_id}', [
    'uses' => 'ControllerName@deleteTeam',
    'as' => 'admin.team.delete'
]);
```

Comment: Or making use of Model Binding: `public function deleteTeam(Country $country, Team $team)  {}` and updating the route to `Route::delete('delete/{country}/{team}'`

Answer (score 0):

Use a sub-query:

```
DELETE FROM country_team
WHERE team_id = (SELECT id FROM Team WHERE name = 'Real Madrid')
```

The select in () will return the id for team 'Real Madrid', 2.  So it will delete entries in country_team if team_id == 2.

Comment: Can i you please write it in laravel and the code should be generic. Not necessarily `Real Madrid` but any other team. I want to be able to pass the id from the blade to the controller.

Comment: From the response I gave, you just put a variable instead of 'Real Madrid' and you are golden.  As to using Laravel specific syntax, I can't help as I do not work in it.  Sorry.

Comment: Okay i am trying  to get the id being passed from the blade to the controller in to a `variable` like you said. But i am stuck with the right syntax for that

Comment: Formulate a new question specific to Laravel, with your code you have up to now.  Laravel gurus will unstuck you for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Well You can simply pass country_id and  team_id and update your delete team as such.

```
public function deleteTeam(Scountry_id,$team_id)
{
    $country = Country::findOrFail($country_id);  
    $country->teams()->detach($team_id);
}
```